# Maximum value stocks, implementation details

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, stl

I was on the interview and was ased this kind of question:

Given stocks with prices:

```
MS  | 500   
Apl | 1000  
Nefx| 500   
MS  | 500
```

Each time a new stock comes we must add to existing one, or if its a new stock just sore it. So the result of this should be `MS - 1000, Apl - 1000, Nefs - 500.`

We should have 2 functions:

```
void add(string, int); // adds new stock  
void display(unsigned n); // displays top n stocks
```

So I implemented like this:

```
unordered_map<string, int> UM;
void add(string s, int n)
{
    auto iter = M.find(s);
    if(s==M.end())
    { 
        M[str] = n;
    }
    else
    {
        M[str] += n; 
    }
}

void display(unsigned n)
{
    std::map<int,string> M;
    for(auto iter = UM.begin(); iter!=UM.end(); ++iter)
    {
        M.insert(make_pair(iter->second, iter->first));
    }
    for(auto iter = M.rbegin(); iter!=M.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        if(n==0){break;}
        cout<<iter->second<<" "<<iter->first<<endl;
        n--;
    }
}
```

Although the add function is quite effective O(1) if the hashing is perfect, the dislpay is too slow, O(NlogN) + n. No matter how many items we must display, we operate all items. Is there a more effective approach to solve the problem, even though it require to change the add function??

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why isn't find O(1) when hashing is perfect?

Comment: How about using a max heap ?

Comment: I need the top N value stocks @Someprogrammerdude, how to find in UM which is not sorted?

Comment: You don't need `find` call in the `add` function. And please be clear about requirements, unclear requirements is a big reason for pain and suffering among programmers and developers.

Comment: This can be accomplished with a structure `using PriceAndTickers = std::set<std::pair<int, std::string>>;` and another lookup structure `std::unordered_map<std::string, PriceAndTickers::iterator>`. With this solution the add is O(log N) and the display is O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add` function should be a one-liner `UM[s] += n;`. Nothing more is necessary.

> the dislpay is too slow, O(NlogN) + n

You can copy pointers to `UM` elements into a vector and do [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) for `n` top elements, complexity `O(size*log(n))`:

```
void display(unsigned n) {
    n = std::min<unsigned>(n, UM.size());
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<decltype(UM)::value_type>> v(UM.begin(), UM.end());
    std::partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + n, v.end(), [](auto a, auto b) { return a.get().second > b.get().second; });
    for(auto p = v.begin(); n--; ++p)
        std::cout << p->get().second << " " << p->get().first << '\n';
}
```

---

With `O(n)` extra storage (instead of `O(N)` above):

```
template<class T, class Less>
void insert_sorted_ref(std::vector<T const*>& v, T const& element, Less&& less) {
    auto i = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), &element, less);
    if(i == v.end()) {
        if(v.size() < v.capacity())
            v.insert(i, &element);
    }
    else if(less(&element, *i)) {
        if(v.size() == v.capacity())
            v.pop_back();
        v.insert(i, &element);
    }
}

void display(unsigned n) {
    std::vector<decltype(UM)::value_type const*> v;
    v.reserve(std::min<unsigned>(n, UM.size()));
    auto greater = [](auto* a, auto* b) { return a->second > b->second; };
    for(auto const& sn : UM)
        insert_sorted_ref(v, sn, greater);
    for(auto const& p : v)
        std::cout << p->second << " " << p->first << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This requires O(N) memory, can be done in O(n) (N being number of elements in total, n the number that you want to display).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Added an `O(n)` storage version.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
struct PriceAndTicker {
    PriceAndTicker(int price, const std::string& ticker)
        : price(price), ticker(ticker) {}

    int price;
    std::string ticker;
};

bool operator<(const PriceAndTicker& lhs, const PriceAndTicker& rhs) {
    return lhs.price > rhs.price
        || (lhs.price == rhs.price && lhs.ticker < rhs.ticker);
}

std::set<PriceAndTicker> priceAndTickers;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::set<PriceAndTicker>::iterator> tickerLookup;

void add(const std::string& s, int priceChange) {
    int newPrice;
    auto it = tickerLookup.find(s);
    if (it == tickerLookup.end()) {
        newPrice = priceChange;
    } else {
        newPrice = it->second->price + priceChange;
        priceAndTickers.erase(it->second);
    }
    tickerLookup.emplace(
        s, priceAndTickers.emplace(newPrice, s).first);
}

void display(size_t n) {
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (auto it = priceAndTickers.begin(); it != priceAndTickers.end(); ++it) {
        if (counter++ == n) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << it->ticker << " " << it->price << "\n";
    }
}
```

The time complexity of `add` is O(log N), and `display` is O(n).